# C# filter does not restores after grid datasourse update

Tags: c#, gridview, filter

There is part of my code:

```
                        if (OnSave())
                    {
                        saveFilter();
                        ReInitDataSource();
                        loadFilter();
                    }
```

saveFilter function:

```
        ViewFilter filter = new ViewFilter();
    private void saveFilter()
    {
        foreach (object filt in GetGridView.ActiveFilter)
        {
            filter.Add((ViewColumnFilterInfo)filt);
        }
        GetGridView.ActiveFilter.Clear();
    }
```

load filter function:

```
        private void loadFilter()
    {
        GetGridView.ActiveFilter.BeginUpdate();
        GetGridView.ActiveFilter.Clear();
        foreach (object filt in filter)
        {
            GetGridView.ActiveFilter.Add((ViewColumnFilterInfo)filt);
        }
        GetGridView.ActiveFilter.EndUpdate();
    }
```

ReInitDataSource() does commit changes to database and upgrades XpoObject collumn Products:

```
                    GridColumn cColProductGroup = cColInfo.ColumnByFieldName(EVNT_BugzillaComponent.Fields.fkProductGroup_this.PropertyName);
                ControlsUtils.InitLookupControlData(cSession, typeof(LIC_ProductGroup), cColProductGroup.ColumnEdit as RepositoryItemLookUpEdit);
```

So there is my problem:
when i restore layout, the gridView1.FilterPanelText becomes "[product]="
I don't know why? can someone suggest any solution.

P.S. if i filter not by XpOobjects but, for example, by string - nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using datablocks to identify the filter easier?!

That way you can define which datablock you would like to initialize.

http://www.centerspace.net/doc/NMath/user/data-2.html